# HtmlAgilityPack c# taking several images and links

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, html-agility-pack

Please help-me with this question:

```
private void DownLoadCompleted(object sender, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e)
{
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml("http://www.unnu.com/popular-music-videos");
    //var query = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img");
    MessageBox.Show("chegou");
    foreach (HtmlNode linkNode in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("@//img[@src]"))
    {
        HtmlAttribute link = linkNode.Attributes[@"href"];
        HtmlNode imageNode = linkNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//.php?src");
        HtmlAttribute src = imageNode.Attributes[@"src"];

        string Link = link.Value;
        Uri imageUrl = new Uri(src.Value);
        MessageBox.Show("chegou");
    }
}
```

I need to get the all images and titles with your respective urls. I'm Using windows phone 7.5. The dll is the same.

Comment: I want to down vote just because you told me not to! ;)

Comment: What error do you get? or What doesn't work?

Comment: The error is: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in AppUnno.dll"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doc.LoadHtml` expects *html*, not the url. Are you looking for something like this?

```
var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load("http://www.unnu.com/popular-music-videos");

var imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//img[@src]")
            .Select(img => new
            {
                Link = img.Attributes["src"].Value,
                Title = img.Attributes["alt"].Value
            })
            .ToList();
```

If HtmlAgilityPack's WP7 version doesn't support *HtmlWeb* you can also use *WebClient* to get the html string and it can be used as parameter to `doc.LoadHtml`

Comment: this method (DownloadCompleted) is already the Continued my call. But not pasted here, sorry. In WindowsPhone is simpler because the call is asynchronous Let me show you how it works:

HtmlWeb.LoadAsync ("http://www.unnu.com/popular-music-videos" DownloadCompleted);

I will test and now spend my feedback!

Comment: your code don't have any erros. But I'm not getting my load list with these data. My xaml is <ListBox Name="listBoxPopular" ItemsSource="{Binding imgs}">
                  
                                <Image Name="imagem" Source=" Binding src"/>
                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding alt}" 
                </ListBox>

Comment: @LuizNegrini I don't remember that your question was about WPF and how to load data to some controls. If you think you can make me answer your further question by *unaccepting* the answer, forget it.

Comment: No, just thought you might know. How do I get separate each list item? (ToList ()).

Comment: please see my other comment.